# Android - Google Maps V2 : Send latitude and longitude coordinates in URL StringBuilder

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, coordinates

I have 2 locations, given by a user.
For exemple with these :
editDepart = France;
editArrivee = England;
(It is really schematically)

Then, to draw my route between these two locations, I do that :

```
        final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&language=fr");
        url.append("&origin=");
        url.append(editDepart.replace(' ', '+'));
        url.append("&destination=");
        url.append(editArrivee.replace(' ', '+'));

        //Calling the Web service
        final InputStream stream = new URL(url.toString()).openStream();
```

Can I replace editDepart=France, by latitude and longitude Coordinates ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Best regards,

Tofuw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it , example url with waypoints :

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=54.3536,18.433146&destination=54.3536,18.433146&waypoints=optimize:true|54.342041,18.56049|53.589802,17.859051|53.539921,17.244459|53.6446,17.70005|53.690319,17.540279|53.541599,18.102133&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=54.3536,18.433146&destination=54.3536,18.433146&waypoints=optimize%3atrue%7C54.342041,18.56049%7C53.589802,17.859051%7C53.539921,17.244459%7C53.6446,17.70005%7C53.690319,17.540279%7C53.541599,18.102133&sensor=false)